# jQuery executes Rails command but does not display result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails app that let's the user right click on DOM items to get a context menu implemented with the tool [jQuery-contextMenu](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html). When the user then clicks on an item in that menu, a Rails action is executed. Up to this point, all this actually works. I then want the page to be refreshed with the altered state of the data. The debug console of Rails claims that the page was displayed correctly but my browser shows no difference. What am I doing wrong?

This is the script inside my HTML page that represents the context menu. If you click on the deletenode option, the $.post request is issued.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#treemenu').contextMenu({
            selector: 'span', 
            callback: function(key, options)
            {
                var nodeID = parseInt($(this).attr("id").substring(13), 10);
                if(key == "deletenode")
                {
                    $.post("/ontology/" + nodeID + "/delnode", { _method: 'post' });
                }
                else if(key == "deletearc")
                {
                }
                else
                {
                }
//              window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
            },
            items:
            {
                "deletenode": {name: "<%= t('ontologies.delete.delete_node') %>"},
                "deletearc": {name: "<%= t('ontologies.delete.delete_arc') %>"},
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Due to the Rails routes, this leads to this Rails action in the controller

```
def delnode
    logger.debug 'Entered delnode ' + params[:id]
    redirect_to ontologies_url, alert: 'testing delnode.'
end
```

And this is the output on the debugger console. As it says Completed 200, it should actually be ok. But the redirect to the index action is not actually happening.

```
Started POST "/ontology/1/delnode" for ::1 at 2017-01-08 19:04:52 -0800
Processing by OntologiesController#delnode as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Entered delnode 1
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

I tried a lot of different things suggested in other posts but nothing results in the page being displayed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delnode` route and method is being called from a ajax request. So, the `redirect_to` method will render a 302 code that's not being handled by your callback.

A possible solution is render a 200 code (operation success, like: "OK, I deleted the node") and, in ajax `done` callback, handle sucess with a redirect.

Something like that:

rails:

```
def delnode
    logger.debug 'Entered delnode ' + params[:id]
    #destroy logic...
    #if ok:
    head 200 #renders nothing
end
```

js:

```
$.post("/ontology/" + nodeID + "/delnode", { _method: 'post' }).done( function(data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    location.reload(); //javascript refresh your page
});
```

Comment: Thank you, mrlew. That solved the problem very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

On AJAX request, you can't use redirect_to method in controller.
You can render an HTML code, data from Model or nothing in controller.

so use code:

```
render :nothing => true
```

or

```
render data: {status: true}.to_json
```

In js:

```
$.post("/ontology/" + nodeID + "/delnode", { _method: 'post' }).done( function(response) {
  console.log("response: "+ response.status) //you will get true in response
  window.location.reload(); //reload the page if you want to reload
})
```